# Which Indian trains have shorter booking period?

Tags: trains, india, bookings

Most of the long distance trains in India have bookings opened 90 days before the train ride.
There are some that have a shorter period available.

Which exact Indian trains have reservations open only 30 day prior to departure?

Comment: I would love to see an answer to this question, but I suspect you may not get one. My experiences in India are that you can't rely on anything to remain consistent - even published schedules/rules, or the ability to purchase tickets online. My friends and I once tried to book train tickets around 10pm and got a message saying the website was "closed" and to try again in the morning. I've never encountered websites being "closed" other than some observant Jewish merchant sites who don't fulfill orders on the Sabbath.

Comment: Indian reservation system closes down for maintenance every day between 23:30-00:30 India time...

Answer (score 3):

From [Seat61](http://www.seat61.com/India.htm):

> Indian long-distance trains open for bookings 90 days before
>   departure.  Some shorter-distance inter-city trains open less than 90
>   days ahead, for example Delhi-Kalka & Kalka-Simla generally open 30
>   days ahead.

There may not be a hard rule which trains fall into the 90 or 30 day category. If you are interested in a particular train, you can try to book it online 60 days in the future and see whether you can book it. You can try [cleartrip](http://www.cleartrip.com) or the [official Indian railway site](https://www.irctc.co.in/)

Interestingly enough cleartrip allows me to book 'Delhi to Kalka' in April 2012 (88 days from now), so the 30 days mentioned above may no longer be correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know I can check whether it can be booked or not but I would like to get the whole list without the need to check each train that crosses my mind.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Indian Railways [site](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/reservation_Rules.html)

> Advance reservations are made generally up to 90 days in advance for all classes and all trains. The period of advance reservation (ARP) is exclusive of the day of departure of the train.
>
> At intermediate stations where the train arrives on the following day,
>   such reservations can be done 91 days in advance of date of
>   journey from the intermediate station. ARP is in relation to the date
>   of journey from train originating station. In case of some Inter-city
>   day trains, the ARP is less.

You can get a partial list (though not official) of Inter city trains from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercity_Express_%28Indian_Railways%29)

Comment: That list is nowhere close to the number of trains that run on the Indian railway network, so it would be deceptive to rely on it. All it lists are *named* Indian trains.